# Parse a JSON array without identical keys

Tags: json, jq

I feel like this is a simple question but I am having trouble finding how to do this in the JQ documentation or other questions on Stack Overflow.

I would like to transform:

```
{
  "articles/guide-1/article-1.html": {
    "href": "articles/guide-1/article-1.html",
    "title": "Article 1",
    "keywords": "keyword-a"
  },
  "articles/guide-2/article-1.html": {
    "href": "articles/guide-2/article-1.html",
    "title": "Article 1",
    "keywords": "keyword-b"
  },
  "articles/guide-3/article-1.html": {
    "href": "articles/guide-3/article-1.html",
    "title": "Article 1",
    "keywords": "keyword-c"
  }
}
```

into `href,title`:

```
articles/guide-1/article-1.html,Article 1
articles/guide-2/article-1.html,Article 1
articles/guide-3/article-1.html,Article 1
```

I have tried using an array index (`.[2]`) and a array/object value iterator: (`.[]`) unsuccessfully.

I have no control how the original JSON is output.

Thank you for any advice or pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.[]` works fine with string interpolation.

```
$ jq -r '.[] | "\(.href),\(.title)"' file
articles/guide-1/article-1.html,Article 1
articles/guide-2/article-1.html,Article 1
articles/guide-3/article-1.html,Article 1
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. SO won't allow me to select as the answer apparently for a couple minutes.